# Дочерние страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, веб-сайт

На [Позитроника](https://positronica.ru/) страница [Бытовая техника для кухни](https://positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/) (пункт меню Бытовая техника для кухни) оформлена как отдельный файл, или же в файле [Позитроника](https://positronica.ru/) происходит замена содержимого на содержимое страницы [Бытовая техника для кухни](https://positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/) при переходе по пункту Бытовая техника для кухни ?

и если с нуля делать, то страницу https://positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/ нужно оформлять как отдельный файл или же встраивать как отдельный файл, который будет подключаться при выборе пункта Бытовая техника для кухни (как лучше)?

Answer (score 1):

Сайт натянут на Битрикс - одну из популярных систем управления контентом. У системы есть шаблонная часть, т.н. каркас сайта (хедер, футер, меню), а всё остальное динамически подгружается из базы данных комплексным компонентом "каталог". Как таковых физических страниц и, соответственно, отдельных файлов там нет.

Это если очень коротко. А вообще Битрикс довольно сложен, если Вам надо что-то редактировать на сайте, придётся его [хотя бы немного изучить.](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/)

Comment: а если без битрикса делать, то страницу https://positronica.ru/catalog/pzkitchen/ нужно оформлять как отдельный файл или же встраивать или как отдельный файл, который будет подключаться при выборе пункта Бытовая техника для кухни?

Comment: @myaccount, подобные сайты (каталоги, магазины) невозможны без систем управления. Не битрикс, так wordpress, opencart и т.д. Вы можете, конечно, попытаться сделать на файлах, которые будут подключаться в зависимости от выбора пункта меню, но это изначально неверное решение.

Comment: я использую wordpress. Каким образом настроить страницу в нем, чтобы отдельный файл встраивался в основную (главную страницу)? (киньте ссылку)

Comment: @myaccount, к сожалению, не подскажу. Возможно, есть какие-то плагины для этого - погуглите.